# Python / Selenium - How to handle mini page refresh after inserting data

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

**Problem:**

- When I open web-page I insert any value to the input
- And when I try to insert data into the next field, it is not possible anymore

  - Why? Because when I inserted data into the first field and deselect it, the page quickly refreshed (within 0.3-0.8 seconds) and because I search for the next field before the refresh... it is not accessible anymore

**Question:**

- Is it any possible way to handle this mini-refresh before searching for the next field?

  - I'm looking for any ideas... theories ...

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a simple `time.sleep()` and search for the next field only after some time has passed.

Comment: sorry I should mention this .... time.sleep() this is what I'm currently using ...... but this small delay could be between 0.3-0.8 seconds and to optimise I would like to use something else ..... but not hardcoded sleep... like....something that will check if page refreshed and can continue ...

Comment: My suggestion would be to implement explicit waits, but i can't tell you exactly how to do it since i don't have access to the website you're currently testing. Some things that come to mind though is if the url changes while the "mini reload" is happening you could use the ```expected_conditions.url_changes``` explicit wait or look for some HTML attributes that show up on the elements only after it has been reloaded.

Comment: URL is not changing ... it is feels like every time information added to the form.. it is happening sort of mini-update to update db or e.t.c... :D

Comment: That sounds like a SPA application, another way to solve this would be to do the following: Check how the site looks before you insert data into the first field and after you inserted the data, what has changed? Did new elements show up? Have attributes of elements changed? If so you could check inside of a try catch block if the values that are supposed to change have changed, and if not retry until they have changed.